# Can Fused heal with Voidlight?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

Book three in *The Stormlight Archives* introduces new creatures called Fused, who can use Voidlight (the opposite of Stormlight) to accomplish similar things as one using Stormlight might do - like Lashings etc. Presumably Fused should be able to use this Voidlight to heal just like Kaladin can do.

My question is, when Moash killed one of the Fused, (who later comes back to life) by stabbing it with a dagger - which is not even close to a Shardblade wound, it should have been very easy for it to heal using Voidlight?

Comment: Fused are somewhat weaker then surgebinders. It's quite possible that voidlight doesn't have as pronounced healing effect.

Comment: They may have no reason to rely on it, being that they seem to be able to come back during a desolation.

Answer (score 2):

They can heal mortal wounds but not Shardblade wounds. see the Coppermind [here](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Fused#Powers). It also seems to work more slowly than Stormlight, being that

> Shallan survives an arrow to the head, and Jasnah surives a knife to the chest.
>
> Whereas, Moash kills a fused by stabbing it in the chest.

Comment: Shouldn't you put "spoiler" instead of "citation"? BTW It's quite possible that healing would be from equivalent of Progression not Voidlight itself.

Comment: Cant be progression the same Coppermind article says that they each only have one power and all of those fused flew